# Is there a way to give the Chrome console tabs permissions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to write a short script so that on some event chrome will open up all the links on a page that match a certain regular expression. I've got all the logic down, I just don't know much about programming for chrome. I googled how to create new tabs in chrome and I found that `chrome.tabs.create` is the method I want. However, when I try to test using the built in javascript console in chrome, it tells me that `chrome.tabs` is undefined. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chrome.tabs` will only be available on extension pages (that is, pages that begin with `chrome-extension://`).  [Create a new extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) and have the [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html) of that extension open the tabs.

You'll need to load code into your ordinary web page with a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) (or inject a file script via [executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) in your background page) that runs your link-gathering logic and the [passes](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) all the URLs to the background page, which can then call `chrome.tabs.create`.

I wish it were easier, but that's really the simplest way.  Background pages have access to the full extension API, but the rely on other scripts to run within ordinary web pages to give them instrustions via message passing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you that there is `tabs` permission in your `manifest.json` file:
https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Comment: [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) does not require tabs permissions.